# How to give an external property to UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode4, ios4, uibutton

I am new in iOS development. Now I want to give an external property(similar to tag) to a UIButton. Is it is possible? If it is possible ,how to do this?

If any body know, please help me.

Comment: Create your custom class from the UIButton.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a NSArray, and the index of the array is the UIButton's tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can either create a `UIButton` subclass, or use Obj-C runtime associations like this

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>

static char kMyExtendedPropKey;
objc_setAssociatedObject(myButton,
                         &kMyExtendedPropKey,
                         yourObjectToAssociate,
                         OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN);
```

Note that associations can be used in conjunction with categories to add new properties to existing classes! But use with caution, **subclassing is the preferred way**.

Answer (score 0):

Subclass UIButton, assuming you want an NSString in your button:

.h

```
@interface MyAttributedButton : UIButton {
   NSString *myExternalProperty;
 }

@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *myExternalProperty;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation MyAttributedButton
@synthesize myExternalProperty;
@end
```